# Error when trying to sort linked list with string comparison

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I have to construct a linked list with some data which is read from a text file and then to sort it.
My structure:

```
struct Person {
int age;
char *name;
struct Person *next;
};

typedef struct Person LIST;
```

The reading from the file:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    LIST *node = (Person*)(malloc(sizeof(Person)));
    node->name = strdup(line);
    node->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        current = head = node;
    }
    else {
        current = current->next = node;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

After this I'm printing out the linked list which looks just fine.

Ideally I should sort by age but I didn't succeed to read the data into separate variables. So I've tried to sort the list by comparing the strings. It says 'nullptr', so I've added two more conditions ((current->name[i]!=NULL) && (current->name[i+1] != NULL)) to my 'if' statement, however getting the same error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if ( (current->name[i]!=NULL) && (current->name[i+1] != NULL) && ( (current->name[i]) > (current->name[i + 1]) ) )
    {

        char temp = NULL;
        current->name[i] = temp;
        current->name[i] = current->name[i + 1];
        current->name[i + 1] = temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: you're sorting the _letters_ of your name

Comment: `current->name` is a char array. but `current->name[i]` is a `char`.

Comment: and why `i < 5`. Where does that come from?

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 rows in the file.

Comment: you're mixing up the characters of name with the length of the linked list.

Comment: and you'll have a hard time sorting a single-linked list. I'd recommend that you put the elements in a resizable array so you can perform your bubble sort (or any other sort) way more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You never read the ages into the Age variable, so you can't sort by age. If you want to sort by name, you want to use the `strcmp(char *a, char *b)` function, which returns -1, 0 and 1, depending on if a < b, a == b or a > b, so your conditional should become:

```
if ((current != NULL) && (current->next != NULL) && strcmp(current->name, current->next.name) > 0)
```

This way you're comparing the actual names of the current node, and the next node, and not comparing the letters of the same name.